# Symfony3 Ajax on textarea with multiple lines error but not on single

Tags: javascript, ajax, textarea, symfony

I want to *save the value of a textarea with some Ajax*.

JS:

```
function saveCommentary(id)
{
    commentary = document.getElementById('commentaire' + id).value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
    $.get(Routing.generate('ajax_savecommentary', { id:id, commentary:commentary }), 
    function(response)
    {
        alert('commentary');
        alert(commentary);
    }, "json");
}
```

I added the *replace* hopping to solve my problem but nope.
When I use ***only one line everything works***, that's why I tried to replace the "\n" with a "" but still nope.

php:

```
public function saveCommentaryAction($id, $commentary)
{
    if (!$this->get('session')->get('compte'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));

    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
    $isAjax = $request->isXMLHttpRequest();

    if ($isAjax)
    {
        $information = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Information')->find($id);
        $information->setCommentaire(nl2br($commentary));
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true, 'commentary' => $commentary);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
    $response = array("code" => 0, "success" => false, 'commentary' => $commentary);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: Solved with "replace(/\n/g, '<\\br>')" and "replace({'<\\br>' : '\n'})" on twig. Still don't know the reason.

Comment: Do not change data using a GET request. GET requests van be cached. Always use a POST or PUT request if you change data.

Comment: What error was generated?

Comment: I'll try monday your way. The problem was there were no specific error
If it works, I'll invite you to post as an answer.